# Android / Samsung Gallery - Changing date taken property

Tags: android, image, datetime, maui

While running out of space on my Samsung Galaxy Device, the 3rd of November 2022, I copied around 3'000 pictures on my SD Card. Bad move : all the pictures I had (especially Whatsapp ones) are now tagged as taken the 3rd of November.

I then wrote an app in .NET MAUI which change the creation / last access time / last written time to be depending on the file name - eg. : IMG-20210627-WA0001.jpg sets those value to the 27th of June 2021 at midnight. I logged the before/after dates and it works well.

Here as an example I set the dates to 28/11/2021 at midnight.

```
DateTime newTime = new DateTime(2021, 11, 28, 0,0,0);
File.SetCreationTime("/storage/3439-3532/DCIM/Test EXIF/IMG-20210627-WA0002.jpg", newTime);
File.SetLastWriteTime("/storage/3439-3532/DCIM/Test EXIF/IMG-20210627-WA0002.jpg", newTime);
File.SetLastAccessTime("/storage/3439-3532/DCIM/Test EXIF/IMG-20210627-WA0002.jpg", newTime);
```

However, in the Gallery App, the files are still displayed at the 3rd of November, and in the pictures info, I still see the wrong date.

Any ideas ?

Comment: check the EXIF data.  There are a huge number of EXIF tools that should allow you to fix this.

Comment: Yes, will do. I tried a EXIF library but it said it had no EXIF data, so I'll try some scénario on my pc with EXIF files.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. : I copied a file from the web with EXIF data (taken in 2008)  : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ianare/exif-samples/master/jpg/Canon_40D_photoshop_import.jpg and copied it to the SD card. It appears as taken at the time the file was copied... I took a picture taken yesterday with my phone, **moved** it to my PC then back to my SD card and it was tagged at the correct date, while picture from Whatsapp moved back and forth have the incorrect date. It seems any file imported on the phone that does not originate from the camera has the wrong time set. Any ideas ?

Comment: This sounds more like a general Android or Samsung issue, not anything to do with software development

Comment: Or maybe it's not EXIF data after all... I'm still doing some tests : it seems that when I change the file's "Date taken" property through Windows Explorer, it _does_ work : I tried with 3 files : they have the same EXIF DateTime but 3 different "Date Taken" in windows, so that's what I'm trying to achieve now.

Comment: Making progress but still stuck. I found some pieces of code, but it uses the System.Drawing.Image especially the Image.FromFile(path) but it says that the .FromFile() does not exist. Same thing for the PropertyItem class from Image.GetPropertyItem. Posts talking about this are quite old (+7 years old) so I guess this is obsolete now. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot a struggling, I finally got it.
@Jason was right, it had to do with EXIF but I looked at the wrong tags : I focused on datetime and date_digitized but those were the wrong ones. I used the website https://exif.tools/ to check what I was looking for, and "Date/Time Original" was the one I was looking for. I didn't find it in the first place because I used a python library to fetch the EXIF data but, alas, the field was not documented in the img.list_all() command of my Python library supposed to list all available EXIF tags (albeit present and reachable)...

Anyways, here's my code as an example in C# MAUI .NET. With the help of EXIFLibNet Nuget package, this took only a few lines.

*In case anyone is wondering (like I did) ImageFile.FromFile comes from the ExifLibrary namespace and not from standard System.XXX namespace.*

```
// Use of Nuget : EXIFLibNet. Add using ExifLibrary;
string imgpath = @"C:\EXIF Cleanup\IMG-20230301-WA0004_01.jpg";
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(2023,03,01);
var file = ImageFile.FromFile(imgpath);
file.Properties.Set(ExifTag.DateTimeOriginal, newDateTime);
file.Save(imgpath);
```

This changed successfully the windows' Date Taken fields in the file property > Details window which seems to be the one taken for the Samsung Gallery => when I copied the resulting file to my device, it showed at the correct date.

Beware though as there are 2 EXIF properties, offset_time and offset_time_original that may cause issue if you don't specify a time for newDateTime : in my test this caused a shift of 2 hours which tagged my picture one day before the 1st of March.

This worked on a MAUI App on my laptop, I'll test this tomorrow on my device and update if needed my answer accordingly if this doesn't work somehow.

Comment: And it did work. The Gallery takes some time to refresh though.